# Paging with GridView and LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, gridview, pagination

My grideview:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="MyGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" 
    OnRowCreated="MyGridView_RowCreated" AllowPaging="true" Width="100%" 
    PageSize="5" onpageindexchanging="MyGridView_PageIndexChanging" >
```

My code behind on page_load:

```
MyGridView.DataSource = new Emp.GetData();
MyGridView.DataBind();
```

My code:

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    var query = //valid query here   

    query = query.Skip(StartRowIndex *5 ).Take(5);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

if i have 15 records in my db, upon page load i see links for page 1,2 3 with data for page 1 shown - 5 records. then when i go to page 2 with 5 records, i see page 1 and 3 links. when i go to page 3 i see only 2 records instead of 5 and sometimes the paging link does not show up correctly either.

I want to display 5 records per page and want the GridView to determine how many pages to show.

i am not using a LinqDataSource, just have a method that returns a list.

Comment: What kind of LINQ? LINQ to XML?

Comment: If i use a linqdatasource I would have have maxrecords and that somehow manages the paging. with gridview most times i do not get the paging links. if i set the take(maxrowcount) then it works at times...

Answer (score 4):

It actually tends to be easier if you do use a `LinqDataSource`.

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server"
    OnSelecting="MyDataSource_Selecting">
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```

And in the code-behind, you can just re-route the `LinqDataSource` to call your business logic layer.  However, it will now need to leave the `DataContext` object open, i.e., don't wrap it in a `using` block, or you will get an error (and also don't apply the manual paging with `Skip(..).Take(..)`.

```
protected void MyDataSource_Selecting(object sender,
        LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e) {
    e.Result = Emp.GetData();
}
```

Now the `LinqDataSource` should manage all the paging for you automatically.

Comment: The problem with this approach is your loading all the data. If there are 10000 records, you'd be loading them all in order to get 5 of them. Skip() and Take() generate the appropriate SQL code so that only what's needed is returned from the database

Comment: No, that's not how a `LinqDataSource` works with paging enabled.  It's smart enough to only grab the records it needs when you give it a LINQ-to-SQL `IQueryable` object.  You just don't close the `DataContext` and call `ToList` first before returning the results.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use the [`PagedDataSource` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pageddatasource.aspx) to achieve this.

[Here's an article](http://www.aspdotnetcodes.com/DataList_Dynamic_Paging_PagedDataSource.aspx) explaining how it works.